# Dificuldades no Scilab

Tags: arduino, serial, scilab

Estou me comunicando via USB -> Serial do Arduino e recebendo valores de um sensor. Mas as vezes valores tem tamanhos diferentes e a função usada para receber os bytes da serial precisa de uma quantidade definida de bytes de entrada. Exemplo: data = readserial(arduino, 3);
O valor de data as vezes recebe também o caractere fim de linha. Portanto achei no Octave, uma função que desempenhava o objetivo de pegar um caractere por vez e parar quando encontrasse um caractere de fim de linha. A função é esta:

Programa do octave:

```
pkg load instrument-control

function [char_array] = ReadToTermination (srl_handle, term_char)    
 % parameter term_char is optional, if not specified
 % then CR = '\r' = 13dec is the default.
if(nargin == 1)
 term_char = 10;
end
not_terminated = true;
i = 1;
int_array = uint8(1);
while not_terminated
 val = srl_read(srl_handle, 1);
 if(val == term_char)
 not_terminated = false;
 end

 % Add char received to array
 int_array(i) = val;
 i = i + 1;
end

 % Change int array to a char array and return a string array
 char_array = char(int_array);
endfunction
```

Eu tenho pouca familiaridade com o Scilab, mas mesmo assim comecei a escrever o programa nele, pois quero usar uma funcionalidade que o Scilab tem e o Octave não. Postarei o programa do Scilab juntamente com o erro.

Programa do Scilab:

```
function [char_array] = read_term(srl_handle, term_char)
not_terminated = 1;
i = 1;
int_array = uint8(1);
while not_terminated
val = readserial(srl_handle, 1);
if(val == term_char)
    not_terminated = 0;
end
int_array(i) = val;
i = i+1;
end
char_array = (int_array); 

endfunction

m = read_term(h,13) %Chamamento da função
```

Erro do scilab:

```
Operação indefinida para os dados operandos.
Verifique ou defina a função %c_i_i para overloading.
at line      10 of function read_term called by :  
m = read_term(h,13)
at line      17 of exec file called by :    
exec('C:\Users\Mateus\Documents\read_term.sci', -1)
```

Agradeço a ajuda.
Mateus Lucas.